# why my mobile site detects google crawler as desktop thus switches to desktop version crawling

Tags: google-search-console

I am struggling to get my mobile site (under m.xxxx.xxx.com subdomain) to be crawled  and indexed by google, via "google search console" and "url inspection' process.

problem is that my mobile site resolves desktop clients only  to a desktop version of the site.

Now,
google bot indexing appears to my site as desktop device , and is redirected to desktop.

is there a way  to define  mobile indexing   only via sitemap ? or robots.txt ?

thanks.

Oded.

Comment: Googlebot based tools typically identify themselves as a mobile devices when crawling, via their User Agent. This includes the URL inspection tool. It sounds like your mobile device detection system is not picking that up.

Comment: thanks. i have not thought of this. 
but when i inspect a list of all   User Agents visitting my site, there is no hint of them being mobile devices.

for instance  :-  "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Barkrowler/0.9; +https://babbar.tech/crawler)"
(visited my site)
thats a crawler no doubt. it does not menrtion its desktop or mobile device .

what have i not understood here ?

Comment: I have checked now Mobile_detect.php  script i am using to id devices. 

it seems its considering bots.     weird!

in any case , i have starting detecting bots via Crawler_user_agent.json parsing and comparing to user agents  incoming instances. 
so far it works perfect  , although probably weighing over the site entering process. 

Thanks  anyway.

Comment: Here's the user agents Google uses. Googlebot typically uses the Smartphone one: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/overview-google-crawlers